# Extrude Along Path (Sharp Corners)?

Tags: modeling, workflow

How can face of cornice be extruded along a given profile 'P' ?

I've used knife tool to cut the long profile at 45 degrees and the  assemble them together but process is long?[image]

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50534/how-do-you-make-a-mitred-corner

Comment: Hi there, I am involved in addressing this issue in Blender (in Geometry Nodes only as of v3.5). This is still in development but closing in on a solution and that'd be great if you could provide some feedback here: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/curve-to-mesh-node-even-thickness-feedback-thread/27271 - Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi there, I am involved in addressing this issue in Blender. This is still in development but closing in on a solution and that'd be great if you could provide some feedback here: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/curve-to-mesh-node-even-thickness-feedback-thread/27271  - Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13):

Try using a curve as a bevel object.

1- Create a curve with the shape you want to use as bevel.
[image]

2- Create a different curve as a new object for the shape you want that bevel object to follow

[image]

3- With the newly created curve selected, go to the curve menu and select the curve you want to use as bevel object and adjust the bevel depth.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: i always struggle to get the curve to have "sharp corner" @ 90 degrees. How Were you able to achieve that at "step 2"? as far as i know the breizer curve can only have smooth angles.

Comment: @NareshVijh You can make a bezier curve be smooth or sharp by changing the handle type. There are four Bezier curve handle types you can use, to select one press V. For 90 degree turns you can use vector. See: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Curves#Editing_Bezier_Curves

Comment: now i get it. thanks. But, i don't know  why.... whenever i extrude it along the path that curve

Comment: @NareshVijh you can post a new question

Comment: @cegaton Whenever i extrude it along the path that curve moulding doesn't face towards desired orientation?

Comment: @NareshVijh with no pictures it's hard to guess what's going on in your case. All I can say is that it's important to keep both objects' axis consistent.