# Rotate without distorting size

Tags: edit-mode, transforms, scale

I'm trying to create a 45 degree angle on a specific sized rectangle. However, when I rotate my end vertices, the size of the rectangle also changes.

How can I rotate without changing the size of my object?

The object on the left is what I am trying to acomplish. The object on the right is what happens if I rotate the two vertices to a 45 degree angle.

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome. I can't understand what you mean, can you show a picture, a drawing or else to help us understanding what you need?

Comment: sorry, Is not clear

Comment: Sorry, I basically want to angle an end of a rectangle 45 degrees.  But when I use the rotate ( R )  tool, with my selected vertices, the rotation makes the end smaller.  I don't want my size to change, just the angle of the end of the rectangle.   Hope that helps.

Comment: Use the [shear](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/50571/935) tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You obviously can't use rotate on vertex, since what you want to achieve is not rotation, it's closer to a cut.

Either use *Knife Project* with a secondary object. Create a plane, rotate it 45º and place it where desired. With still selected, enter *Edit Mode* in your rectangle and use *Knife Project*

[image]

If you rectangle as known dimensions you can simply move one vertex horizontally the same distance as its height.

[image]

Comment: You might just hit `K` in edit mode, snap the cursor to one corner, klick once, press `C` to activate snap to angles and click again at the edge of the rectangle in an 45° angle. Angle snap will help to get the exact spot and no temporary geometry is needed. You need to view it straight from above to make it work as intended.

Comment: @Cebbi I tried had tried with the *Knife* but didn't know about that *Angle Snap* feature. `C` key did it, that is awesome! Should post that as a new answer bellow.

Answer (score 11):

The command you are looking for is called SHEAR. Select the vertices you want to rotate and press <kbd>Space</kbd> and type in "shear" (or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> at the same time)

Comment: Wow, this should be marked as answer, so instinctive except the name "shear".

Comment: Nevermind, this method is not as useful as I thought, but maybe It's 2.8 alpha's problem.

Comment: THANK YOU. seriously.

Comment: This bumps up my modelling game. Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 5):

Use the knife tool <kbd>K</kbd> and press <kbd>C</kbd> to activate angle snapping.