# Boolean modifier difference issue

Tags: modifiers

I've been testing with a ramp and attempting to make a pillar that holds up the ramp and want to add a boolean modifier to the ramp, that way the top of the ramp can be sectioned away but whenever I try to do so, it deleted the ramp entirely. NOTE: The ramp and pillar both have thickness.[image]

Comment: You cannot get what you want with the two objects as you have them. The pedestal is not even bifurcated by the ramp. The ramp should be either higher, or temporarily changed to a solid cylinder or half-cylinder.

Comment: Wow my bad, I really should of realized that. Being the beginner I currently am I don't honestly know how to make the cylinder solid, so some instructions from more experienced users like yourself would be nice, thank you!

Comment: If you just want to chop off the top of the ramp use *Knife Project* operator instead, its a lot more suited for what you want to do. See [both](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68591/rotate-without-distorting-size/68618#68618) these [answers](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63719/cut-out-surplus-material/63721#63721) for more details

Comment: I think there may be some confusion, I don't want to cut the ramp at all. I'd like to cut the bit where the pedestal bisects the ramp.

Comment: In that case the ramp has to cut the pedestal completely, as it currently stands there would be leftover bits still connected. Also avoid Booleans  operations in the long run, they are not a proper modeling method for meshes, and will only bring trouble down the road sooner or later.

Comment: Okay, how do you suppose I cut the pedestal? The only method I know is using the boolean modifier.