# Simple Rotation problem

Tags: mesh

I am almost embarassed to ask something so simpe, but can someone give me a pointer as to how to rotate a surface 45 degrees without the distortion and maintaining dimensions. See attached.[image: T]

Thanks

Richard C

Comment: Duplicate question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68591/rotate-without-distorting-size Includes GIFs! ;-)

Comment: Duarte's right, the question is well covered in his reference.. In my answer, I've tried to describe the 'Cut' option better ..

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: it's not a rotation.  If you visualize the circular rails around which the vertices would travel in a rotation, you can see that.

If you wanted a *transform* to do the job, on parallel rails, it would be a shear. (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>). But that's expressed in terms of offset, which would be half the length of the vertical edge to get 45 degrees, and would be awkward.

So the best idea here is probably a cut. Hit <kbd>K</kbd> and left-click on your starting vertex. It should highlight green. Hit <kbd>C</kbd> to snap the cut to 45 degrees, (and <kbd>Z</kbd> if you need to cut through more than one layer of faces), and move the mouse over to the opposite edge, until you see the highlight again. Left-click to 'plant' the other end of the cut, and the Space bar to confirm it.

[image]

Comment: I think it may be beneficial to add images to illustrate some of your points.

Comment: @RayMairlot   Wilko.. but I can't get to that for a while..

Comment: Why not just scale to 0 on an axis: S X 0 ?

Answer (score 1):

Other options :

Flip the extrude edge along the X axis :

[image]

Or move the pivot point (center of rotation) to the lower of the 2 vertices of the extruded edge and rotate about that :

[image]