# How to skew edge loops

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I want to add straps by skewing edge loops.

[image]

Comment: Use [shear](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/50571/935) - Ctrl-Alt-Shift-S

Comment: [Blender calls it shear. (Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S)](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/transform/shear.html)