# Proper inheritance rotation

Tags: modeling, workflow, edit-mode, vertices

Just curious, is it possible to make a proper rotation without tweaking after?

**From**

[image: From]

**Too**

[image: too]

Comment: Related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50534/how-do-you-make-a-mitred-corner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to **[shear](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/transform/shear.html)** the vertices / edge loops.

Select the edges/vertices in edit mode.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to go into the shear operation.
During the operation you can press <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Y</kbd> to constrain it to the respective axes. In my example I enter the number -1:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>-</kbd>

After that simply extrude in the X direction then scale it to zero along the x axis.

[image]