# Building corners: How to connect 2 walls with a straight corner

Tags: modeling

Hello I'm strugling with this task that I suppose should be quite easy :P

I've two walls with the same shapes and profiles, those two should be placed at the corner of a building, I'm looking for a way to **close the gap** between the walls. I could probably do it manually, but I'm pretty sure it should be done in an automatic way using some techniques or tools that I'm not aware of.

Attached you find an image with **top** and **perspective** views, in green the result I'd like to obtain (sorry... it has badly hands-drawn) probably it is not very clear from the image, but I'd like to close the corner continuing the wall shape having the two walls "merged" at 90 degs.

Any idea?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you make a mitred corner?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50534/how-do-you-make-a-mitred-corner)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

3 methods (or surely more):

1/Bridge edge loops (1):

- Select the corresponding vertices
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> then bridge edge loops
- Select edges from bottom to top <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd>
- Scale 0 using individual origins as pivot
- Remove doubles
- Select the corner
- Scale by 2 for X and Y from the cursor placed at the inner corner

[image]

2/Bridge edge loops (2):

- Select the corresponding vertices
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> then bridge edge loops
- Set number of cuts to 1
- Set interpolation to blend surface
- Set smoothness to sqrt(2)

[image]

3/Rotation

- Select the wanted vertices on one side
- Place the cursor at the inner corner
- Set the pivot to 3D cursor
- Rotate 45 degrees
- Scale sqrt(2) for X and Y
- Do the same for the other side

[image]

Comment: Fantastic answer. 3 options and perfect explanations.btw, I love option 2.

Answer (score 5):

How about the [shear tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/transform/shear.html). (Yes there is a tool for this, but it takes some set up.)

First make sure the two wall sections meet in the corner (vertex snapping will help here).

With that out of the way, (for your example) go to top view. Set the 3D cursor location to one of the vertices in the very corner. Set the *Pivot Point* to *3D Cursor*.

[image: walls in corner with 3D cursor location marked]

**Remember to be in top view** Select a whole edge (like I have in the image above) now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> and type `1`.
The shear tool is biased off of the active view. (that is why you must be in top view for it to work.) It then defaults to shear along the *X axis*, remember it works in **screen space**.
[image: top view]
So to shear the selected edge, we have to shear along the **Y** axis.

Repeat for the other edge and you have a perfect corner. (Well after you *Remove Doubles*).

[image: animated gif showing how to shear a corner, because everybody likes gifs]

Comment: another great answer. I've accepted the @lemon answer aready but also this answer has a lot of sense.