# Blender do not show strokes when importing SVG

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, import, svg

It does not seem to be a common issue so I must be doing something wrong..

I am using Blender for converting drawings made in Illustrator into meshes in order to import them as .fbx into Unreal engine.

The operation runs smooth.

Though, I noticed something strange on the drawings, that the strokes (their outlines) disappear when I import the SVG into Blender.
Only filling colors stays.
SVGs seems to be properly exported and show up well if I open them in a browser.

Does anyone has a clue on what I might be doing wrong? O.O

Comment: I don't think the svg importer supports anything other than the shape, which, once imported you can choose to fill as a 2D curve or do something else with the outline.

Comment: Thank you cegaton, you confirm what I was suspecting. :/
It will be a bit of a hassle to work it out this way..
I figured I could simply use a high resolution .png mounted on a sprite in Unreal for achieving the effect I was looking for.. much simpler and effective!
thank you for your answer!

Comment: Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87253/can-i-extrude-a-path-in-x-y/