# how to use hair particle system for a maze?

Tags: particles

I used a maze generator to create a 10 by 10 maze and I would like to replace the walls with a tree object I made using the hair particle system but doenst work. I imported the maze as an svg then converted all the curves(chose 3d curve type) into a mesh.

[image]
I created a hair particle system for the maze and selected my object tree. As shown above, the tree is only one, but i want it on all the lines, doesnt work even when i randomize it
[image]
it turns into the wheel of fortune, instead of moving all aroud the line. How to solve please?

Comment: You need faces for the particle system to work

Comment: faces? sorry, im a bit of a beginner, how do i create faces for the maze?

Comment: You maze mesh needs to have faces, you can use this before converting your SVG to mesh https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87253/can-i-extrude-a-path-in-x-y/87254

Comment: Solved it, thanks for the help