# How to create a plane with ornaments that resembles a book cover or a wedding card?

Tags: modeling

As you may know, I am new to Blender, trying different things that came to my mind. So can anyone help me in achieving the below one on my plane?

[image: Border Design]

I want it on a plane that may resemble a book cover or wedding card etc, not on an empty grid.

And tell me any easy and quickly complete way with a video or step-by-step images, please.

[image: plane]

As you asked *"You did not show any reference images of what it should look like. You didn't say what you have tried or where you are stuck"*:

This is what I wanted to achieve with those designs and I'm stuck not knowing how to do it because I was new.

[image: this design]

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Please help me with it i can learn the words what they were called

Comment: You already have the words in the description. Something like "*Plane which may resembles book cover or wedding card*" sounds good enough for me

Comment: why was there is a -1 next to question, can anyone tell me

Comment: Someone downvoted your questions but didn't leave a comment on why. Given your questions I'm going to assume the reasons are lack of research and lack of effort from your part. It is not very clear what you are trying to achieve, if you want to use a texture or a modeled detail. You did not show any reference images of what it should look like. You didn't say what you have tried or where you are stuck.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87253/can-i-extrude-a-path-in-x-y/

Comment: I added the reference image of how i wanted it should look like, now can you u tell me how can i achieve this easily in minutes please

Answer (score 2):

### Approximate with polygons

Depending on your project's needs, you can also consider to simply approximate the curves with a bunch of polygons. If you look at the model from a certain distance, they will be almost indistinguishable from curves based models.

Start by importing the reference image:

[image]

Then add a plan, adjust its size, pick an edge and crtl+left clik your way on the curve adjusting the size and orientation of the new segment with S and R

[image]

Now take advantage to repeating patterns or simmetry with the *array* or *mirror* modifier, like in this case.

[image]

Add some depth with the *solidify* modifier and *bevel* the edges for a smoooth contour.

[image]

Comment: Please tell me how you do with two planes at a time in second image and how did you attached it to the plane in last one

Comment: In the second image I'm modeling with the mirror modifier enabled (shown in the third picture), so what I'm creating is being reflected using the object geometry origin as mirror point (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/mirror.html).
The two planes are just one on top of each other. Nothing fancy. If you have curved surfaces, you can use the Shrinkwrap Modifier to couple them.

Comment: So you are saying if i'm using bezier curve instead of plane then have to use Shrinkwrap modifier in place of mirror modifier or u are saying something different

Comment: This proposal doesn't involves bezier curves. What exaclty are you referring to?

Comment: You said " If you have curved surfaces, you can use the Shrinkwrap Modifier to couple them", i thought if i want to use bezier curve in place of plane in second image then use shrinkwrap modifier in place of mirror modifier, may be i was wrong here in understanding it so what do u mean/refereeing to "Curved Surfaces" & "Shrinkwrap" in above

Comment: Yes you can use the Shrinkwrap modifier on bezier curves too like you are imagining. You can also add multiple modifiers, one after the other. If you have a peculiar geometry, add a some details in the question post so we can have a better understing of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138820/discussion-between-ramos-and-carlo).

Answer (score 1):

This type of design is called "ornaments".

Blender Secrets has very good videos on the subject, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3sEBu2lZbOM) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgFBnEw86W8).

Blender Daily aslo has a [full tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJsxKWxAhMk) on the subject.

And if you need inspiration check out "The Grammar of Ornament" by Owen Jones. You have ornaments from all over the world, this book is a treasure.

[image]

Comment: yes will look in to it

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can do it.
My approach would be the one Blender secret uses here:
https://youtu.be/cgFBnEw86W8

You can either use your image as a reference and draw your curves over it.
Or you can directly import an svg if you have one (and probably clean it).

[image: Drawing Curves Workflow]

Then you can duplicate your pattern as you see fit and attach it together with F.

You also can sculpt or model your patterns by hand in specific cases.

Hope that clarifies it!

Comment: Ok will watch the video and try but how to achieve it on a plane or something i already have