how can i make several different vertices equidistant?
I'm having trouble modeling a logo, I want it to be nice and even throughout, but when I rotate etc. the size appears to be bigger or smaller and it makes the logo look wonky. is there a simple fix?

I also plan to "subdivision surface" it to make the heart look smooth, will that ruin it?

Make half of it and use a mirror, apply the mirror if the little gap is intended, make the gap

that would work here because its symmetrical, but is there a way to make each "segment/group" of vertices equidistant? like what if the mesh wasn't symmetrical? sorry im totally a beginner

Loop Tools add-on has relax and space functions. Relax takes the curvature into account. You can get it from the extensions platform or install any other way. In older versions it used to come with Blender and it used to be possible to just enable it in the preferences.

You can use it on existing loops, it has the option to affect parallel loops as well. Remodeling might not be a bad idea, you could use part of a circle to make it nice and smooth in the first place, but that's 3d modelling in general.

This looks like the work for a bezier curve, where you wouldn't even need to worry about that

i agree @DuarteFarrajotaRamos but how can i make the sharp corners using a bezier curve?

You can set handle type to vector, what issues do you anticipate? See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87253/can-i-extrude-a-path-in-x-y/87254#87254
