Why are the curve extrusions never sharp when tilted 90 degrees?
Curves are great. With curves one can significantly simplify modelling of many elements common to a lot of scenes - roads, beams, pipes, walls, etc.
It is more convenient to create walls when these extrusions face "up", as it makes wall thickness trivial to estimate when looking top-down and also shows the direction normals. To do so, the curve points must be tilted by 90 degrees:


Immediately, the problem is apparent. Curves (of all types) have this annoying quirk that the "sharpness" of 90 deg turns is lost when the median tilt is adjusted, and the thickness seems to receive some sort of linear interpolation to it. The 90-degrees sharp turns of the tilted curve can be "restored" by manually adjusting the "Radius" value of every single point (doable, but obviously not practical):

I understand that it is possible to create perfectly 90-deg angled even-thickness walls using the solidify modifier in conjunction with the curve (as shown in fig.3). But the question remains:

Why does curve extrusion thickness vary when the curve is tilted?
Is there some sort of hidden interpolation going on?
Any way to disable that?


https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66353/how-to-make-beveled-90-degree-corners-on-a-curve-better https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56079/how-can-i-make-a-perfect-sweep-with-bevel-object-in-bezier-curve3d-pipe https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87253/can-i-extrude-a-path-in-x-y/87254#87254

The corners are smaller because there the tangent has a 45° angle.
So when a profile or the extrusion has a width of e.g. 1 m, it is 1 m in X direction at one endpoint and 1 m in Y direction on the other endpoint.
On the corners however this width of 1 m is angled 45° diagonal, which results in a width of only $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ or about 0.707 m.
To conquer that you have to scale the radius by a factor of $\sqrt{2}$ or add more points (but then the corners will still look weird) or change the curve from 3D to 2D, which will mean that all points stay in the XY plane and cannot be moved up or down.
But a 2D curve cannot be tilted, so if you want a flat profile instead of vertical walls, you cannot use the Extrude setting of the curve, you have to specify another curve object, here I use a simple short straight line with a width of 0.4 m:

And here as a comparison the 3D curve, as you can see the corners keep the 0.4 m width of the profile line, but since they are diagonal, their X and Y width is smaller than 0.4 m:

By the way, the same "annoying quirk" happens with the Solidify modifier when you have Even Thickness disabled (as it is by default):

