# Radius is different even though mean radius is the same on beveled curve

Tags: bezier-curves, bevel

The scale and mean radius on this beveled curve are all set to 1 yet the radius on that one vertex is is smaller than every other radius. How do I fix this and make them the same radius?

[image]

Comment: Probably there isn't any direct way to solve that, only workarounds, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66353/how-to-make-beveled-90-degree-corners-on-a-curve-better

Comment: The "mean radius" may be 1 for them all, but "mean" is the _average_ radius for all the selected vertices. So if you have three vertices and the first has a radius of 0.5, the second has 1.0 and the third a radius of 1.5, they still have a mean radius of 1. If you select all and set a mean radius of 1 and they are now all the same size but one is smaller, this can only be if that small one has a radius below 1 and the others slightly above 1. If this problem only occurs with one vertex, select it, set it to 1, then select all the others and also set them 1.

Comment: Hi there, I am involved in addressing this issue in Blender. This is still in development but closing in on a solution and that'd be great if you could provide some feedback here: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/curve-to-mesh-node-even-thickness-feedback-thread/27271  - Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> That doesn't answer the question (The answer would be found [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/66367/145249)), but just to refute @Melodicpinpon's statement that it is not possible to set the radius of multiple points to a single value.

Mark the points you want to influence and select from the *Curve Context Menu* the entry *Set Curve Radius*.

The *Curve Context Menu* is visible when you call it up with the <kbd>RMB</kbd> (right mouse button).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For a single vertex, you can edit it inside the Menu>Item>Transform>Radius;
but for several at once, it seems impossible at the moment.