# How should I make a round 'bevel object' follow my pyramid with no faces?

Tags: modeling, bevel, bezier-curves

First time using Blender so my understanding of how it works might be off.

What I'm trying to make top left, how I'm approaching the issue top right - result bottom left

[image: What I'm trying to make top left, how I'm approaching the issue top right - result bottom left]

So I'm trying to make a shape that consists of two pyramid, on smaller flipped upside-down on top of the other. I want it with no surfaces, but a thickness in form of a circle.

While I expected the edges to be sharp at first try, I also expected a more "symmetric" result.

1. Why does the circular bevel tends to increase in size from edge-to-edge?
2. Is it a "one click" option to tell Blender that I want this wire-object (top right in my image) to have a circular thickness in a more elegant way that what I'm doing?
3. Is it a way to make the corners join elegantly with a sharp 90-degree angle when beveling or should I have smooth corners in the wireframe as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make beveled 90 degree corners on a curve better?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66353/how-to-make-beveled-90-degree-corners-on-a-curve-better)

Comment: Thanks, read this and it does help me with promlem 3 - thanks!

Comment: Try this, it does not produce exactly what you want, but maybe good enough. Add a Wireframe Modifier to your double pyramid then a SubSurf Modifier set to Simple and 2 subdivisions and then add another SubSurf Modifier set to Catmull-Clark and 4 subdivisions.

Comment: Thanks Rob - exciting idea and certainly a lot closer! It is now a lot rounder and "friendlier" in the shape. But the exact numbers you gave me resulted in a very thin frame - possible to add thickness?

Comment: UPDATE: I added a Soldify modifier, this helped with the thickness! I has a lot of weird artefacts/geometry, but I'm very close to my vision now. :D