# Bevel on curve and acuirate 90-degrade angle

Tags: bezier-curves, bevel

It is necessary to place the profile on the wall (given the doors and windows, bends under 90)
I use a curve along the wall, with a bevel.
I can't get a beautiful bends, somehow everything is shifted.
Why is that?
Can this method achieve a accurate profile rotation under 90?
Subdivide curve get an as beds results [How to make beveled 90 degree corners on a curve better?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66353/how-to-make-beveled-90-degree-corners-on-a-curve-better)
[image]
[image]

Comment: there was a similar question here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66353/how-to-make-beveled-90-degree-corners-on-a-curve-better

Comment: It is not that. I put a link to this question. There are rounded corners, and I need straight lines (under 90)