# Getting 90 degrees out of a bezier path

Tags: modeling, vertices, bezier-curves, splines

So trying to create this wire and I can't seem to find the solution for how to keep the end from collapsing, or pinching, on itself when making a turn like this. Tried adding more points but that doesn't work. Neither does rotating or trying to scale.  Tried modifying the title and the 'W' control point and got to the second image, but still basically the same issue.

I could probably find a way around it (add more "cable" or something to bypass the tight corner) but I feel like it's one of those things I'll run into again and again so here I am. Help, please :-)[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66353/how-to-make-beveled-90-degree-corners-on-a-curve-better

Comment: Sadly that's not really solving my issue, as the whole end of that wire is collapsed, even if I extrude it. I had to add a bunch of points to even get it to convert to poly, and the handles didn't lay out like the example, so it was no dice. It's not pinching into a corner like the example you posted, either.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution I found myself was to use the 'Spin" tool on the end where I wanted it to turn. Since it's not going to be seen close up, and for the asset I'm building this should suffice. Wish there was a better way to do this.