# Curve has Rounded Edges. Sharp edges wanted

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, import, edges

I imported a wavefront (obj) with curvedata from Rhino. My problem is, that all curves have a rounded edge when I look at them in object mode. In edit mode, everything looks good. When I convert the curves to an object, the rounded edges are still there. But that is not what I want. The only way I found worked a little is to bump up the resolution. But it never gets sharp. Does anyone have an Idea how I can convert these Objects into meshes with sharp corners?
The other thing is that I have to do that step for every curve. So if there is any way to do all curves at one or to copy the objectdata of a curve to all the other ones, it would save me some time.

What I also tried:

-setting the curve to 2d (but then it disappears)

-Applying Rotation and Scale

I already found that question:
[How to make beveled 90 degree corners on a curve better?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66353/how-to-make-beveled-90-degree-corners-on-a-curve-better) But it didn't work somehow.

If anyone has a better Idea to create all planes, please let me know (I also have all vertices exported as you can see in the images(but all of them are one object)) Or if there is a better way to export curves out of rhino.

Thank you in advance

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I see you are using GIS addon so why to import those data from Rhino? Anyway it is really weird ... It looks like you use some modifier?  Cna you share a blend file ... It can be just one object from your screen . https://blend-exchange.com/  to manipulate with all parts you can Join them or when all aelecten use right click on parametr and choose Copy to Selected from menu.

Comment: @vklidu my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Speaking to Rhino ... check if your curve is not NURBS type ... if so switch to Poly ...

[image]