# Using bevelled curves to wrap a profile around an object results in squished sides?

Tags: modeling, bevel

I'm having the following problem and would hope someone can help me there. I usually use curves to wrap a profile around an object, e.g. a cornice around a building. This however results in squished sides when there are edges, as can be seen in the picture as well. I know why it happens (the profile is projected in a 45° angle on the edge) and how to solve it afterwards, but with a complex object it is quite annoying to scale it with squrt(2) at every corner. Is there a solution to avoid this alltogether and have all sides of the resulting cornice be parallel to the object?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance! :)

[image]

Comment: in the panel, under Shape, try to enable 2D instead of 3D

Comment: I tried this already, but seems to me it literally brings the curve in a 2 dimensional setting, bringing it to z=0 and flattening it in the process if it had a more complex shape, so this wasn't a suitable solution to me

Comment: are you sure you were able to do it with a 3D curve?

Comment: No, as the cirve was turned into a 2d curve, making it unasable for cornices where I use it https://imgur.com/GOG1LF6

Comment: see here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66353/how-to-make-beveled-90-degree-corners-on-a-curve-better

Comment: it's a limitation of Blender, for the moment, if you use 3D shape, you won't get a rectangular corner. I think it's in the todo list ;)

Comment: This is disappointing. But thanks for the heads-up!