# How to get even, straight edges using bevel profiles and curves?

Tags: bezier-curves

I have a nice method for creating pipes and moldings, but there's an issue I'm coming across that ruins the final result.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

And here is how I am doing it in Blender:
[image]

So basically I make that shape with vertices, and then convert to a curve, add some depth and use a bevel profile. But I get this:
[image]

Notice how that shape on the left is tapering. I do not want that. Now there is a solution - all you need to do is bevel the vertices beforehand, but I don't want that. I want perfectly sharp edges like was shown in the first picture.

You can also set the Twist Method to Tangent, but it doesn't look right. Only one side gets thickness.

Any idea how that is very similar to my workflow? I could of course hand model all of it, but I prefer the easier approach.

Blender file:
[image]

Comment: could you upload a sample file?  ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: I added the file.

Comment: I don't think it's possible or you'll need to manually tune the curve vertex radius where needed.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66353/how-to-make-beveled-90-degree-corners-on-a-curve-better

Comment: You can get slightly better results by scaling each of the control points to 0 individually, and setting the vector type to Vector (which I think you've already done;) but in the end you're always going to have problems with the compound corners.