# Bending objects along a curve

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I do not know English, so I will use a translator.
how can you curve the mesh at angles?
That is, there is a curve, and there is a cube, you need to bend it along the curve but that it is bent along this curve.

yandex translate
[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56079/how-can-i-make-a-perfect-sweep-with-bevel-object-in-bezier-curve3d-pipe and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66353/how-to-make-beveled-90-degree-corners-on-a-curve-better/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the curve modifier, just make sure that your model has sufficient geometry.  If you select your model, go to the modifiers tab, and select the curve and deformations axis, then it will deform your model on the curve that you selected.

[image]