# Bevel not matching the curve object source

Tags: bezier-curves, bevel

I am trying to use the Bevel-Object field in the curve object. However the bevelled curve does not match the referenced curve in the X and Y direction (they do match in the Z direction).

[image]

The scales of both curve objects are at 1.00 for all axis. I think the problem might have something to do with the curve radius for bevelling but this is also set to 1.000 and I can only find a mean control value (not a value for the separate axis)

What is the best way to correct the difference accurately?

[blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g22TtoQrjXglUhuQStBq5KKgEhSm4lVy/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56079/how-can-i-make-a-perfect-sweep-with-bevel-object-in-bezier-curve3d-pipe/56115#56115  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66353/how-to-make-beveled-90-degree-corners-on-a-curve-better/66367

Comment: In this case, I think turning the main curve to 2D should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn the base curve to 2D. That will adjust the corners profile to the bevel object:

[image]

2D curves have limitation though: they need to be planar.

If 3D, the corner profile corresponds to the bevel object rotated 45°. So this is matter of choice.

Comment: Great, so to use the 3D option I scaled my profile curve (in edit mode) in the X direction by sqrt(2)/1.