# how to make curve bevel turning evenly?

Tags: modeling

I use a square curve to be the bevel. With default settings. The result is like this.
[image]

More description:

*My purpose is to make a bunch of foot line all around room. I want to use poly spline type curve to achieve this.*

Without bevel object the curve geometry looks like this. The cross section is twisted at the corner which causes a shrink in the middle. Any way to prevent this?

[image]

samplefile:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M3i4IbUPOPmV305ooXImfbh4ZBL0aU10/view?usp=sharing

Comment: could you give more context on what you are trying to accomplish?  I'm not quite sure what you're trying to say

Comment: I guess your problem is that, on the top of the panel you're showing (the curve Object Data), Shape needs to be 2D and not 3D

Comment: hello is known issue from the curve modifier, i think this is related https://developer.blender.org/T40174

Comment: Thanks for the reply. More description are added in the post. I use 2d curve to be the bevel, even without bevel object, it behave the same.

Comment: could you please share your file? (curve + bevel object)

Comment: @moonboots Thanks for the help. I added a sample file in the post.

Comment: so it looks like it works fine if you switch to 2D, no?

Comment: Change the radius for the middle point

Comment: (the main curve should be 2D, not the bevel object)

Comment: @susu Thansk, it is a solution but hard to precise.

Comment: radius will deform in all axis

Comment: @lemon what do you mean about '2d curve' exactly? They are just curves.

Comment: as @moonboots suggested, the main curve has to be 2D to have the corner you want (not the bevel curve). But so the main curve is 2D only.

Comment: For instance: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149830/bevel-not-matching-the-curve-object-source/149833#149833

Comment: @lemon I get it!!! Big thanks!!!

Comment: Thank you all in the comments. I get want I want:D

Comment: @lemon Yes, I get it. Thanks.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66353/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56079/

Comment: Hi there, I am involved in addressing this issue in Blender. This is still in development but closing in on a solution and that'd be great if you could provide some feedback here: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/curve-to-mesh-node-even-thickness-feedback-thread/27271  - Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Make the spine curve 2D is the key.

[image]