# 3D curve with angles does not produce consistent and straight profile

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, topology

I have a mesh and separated a line of vertices in order to create a curve object out of it. Then proceeded to add a custom profile to it.

But the issue is that the output of the profile is neither straight, nor with consistent width.
[image: the uneven profile]

In the top view, its further visible, that where the arch of the design is, the 3D curve is severely distorted. Here is the top view:
[image: top view]

It notable that when converting to 2D curve, the distortion is fixed but it also loses the arch design.

[image: 2D curve]
Front:
[image: 2d curve front]

I could only find this developer thread but with no solutions: https://developer.blender.org/T47230

Thank you.

The blend file: [image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66353/how-to-make-beveled-90-degree-corners-on-a-curve-better https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56079/how-can-i-make-a-perfect-sweep-with-bevel-object-in-bezier-curve3d-pipe https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/259501/inconsistent-thickness-of-curve-profile-using-geometry-nodes/

Comment: It may be that there is no good solution for this. As far as I know it might be best to just construct the thing out of separate parts with 2d curves and join them converted to mesh. But maybe some of Geometry Nodes wizards can do some of their magic here. Maybe edit the question and add Geometry Nodes tag to attract their attention.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I had an idea about it being a "known limitation" about the ends of the curve, but I wasn't sure about the distorted bends/arch. Anyways I also found one tutorial which is aimed at producing lot like what I need to. So for anyone else, this might be useful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1lx-hZGkWNk