# Mesh to Curve Geometry Bevel Round is not really circular

Tags: modeling

So for test I just added a Cube, top quad to one element, bottom quad to one element.
Convert Mesh to Curve, you can see they are closed curves.
Using Properties - Geometry - Bevel - Round

it actually does not have a Round profile, its "squished"

How can I make them totally round profile with Curve or with Splines methods? That should be possible, actually...

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66353/how-to-make-beveled-90-degree-corners-on-a-curve-better https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/259501/inconsistent-thickness-of-curve-profile-using-geometry-nodes

Comment: Hi there, I am involved in addressing this issue in Blender (in Geometry Nodes only as of v3.5). This is still in development but closing in on a solution and that'd be great if you could provide some feedback here: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/curve-to-mesh-node-even-thickness-feedback-thread/27271 - Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a solution. Because it actually works with e.g. Curve - Rectangle or Curve - Angle and add another point for Rectangle.

If you have a Mesh, for instance a plane, and convert it to curve. It must be in localspace only x and y and then it must be set to 2D in Curve Properties Shape and Fill Mode: None

Then the round bevel is even circular. And then you must rotate the object in worldspace only. That's limiting workflow. But it works...
Idk if this is actually a bug in 3D mode.

[image]

They also have the nicer function for 3D curve-type in development for a long time, but it's not easily to implement in existing blender versions.

Also with Geometry Nodes are good solutions:
https://blenderartists.org/t/z-curve-sweeper-for-blender-3-0-curve-to-mesh-with-superpowers/1365277