# Get Rid of Creases due to "Curve to Mesh" Geometry Nodes Profile Curve

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry, extrude, procedural

I have a 2D polyline curve:
[image]

On this curve I add these geometry nodes:
[image]

My resulting geometry has these weird creases in it. What would be the simplest way to get rid of them?
[image]

I have tried resampling the curve and that didn't quite work. Also if the solution is to add geometry it would be ideal to keep the increased geometry around the corners only because I'm going to have a few thousand of these curves in my project, so efficiency is key here.

Comment: You can try to add a fillet with Fillet Curve node (or Curve Fillet ?)

Comment: I am not quite clear what the result should be. Should it be sharp corners with uniform thickness, or rounded corners? And why do you use *Geometry Nodes* here at all, if you can achieve that with Curve Bevel as well?

Comment: @Gorgious Thanks. That is a life saver. Helped me achieve exactly what I want to achieve.

Comment: @Gorgious Are you going to write an answer or do you want me to do it? ;-)

Comment: @quellenform Please do :)

Comment: If your question has been solved, please be so kind and mark the answer that contributed to the solution as "Accepted answer" so that this question will not continue to be displayed as unsolved. Thank you! Here you can find more information: [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you still haven't gotten a solution to your question, please be kind enough to address it.

Comment: Hi there, I am involved in addressing this issue in Blender. This is still in development but closing in on a solution and that'd be great if you could provide some feedback here: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/curve-to-mesh-node-even-thickness-feedback-thread/27271 - Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

From the comments, it appears that you want to extrude a profile and have the corners evenly rounded.

You can solve this relatively easily with the node `Fillet Curve`:

[image]

Note that the radius for the rounding must be the same as the radius of the profile curve and *Poly* must be selected.

[image]

PS: If you need instead a profile with constant thickness and peaked corners, you can solve it this way:
[Solving Uneven Profile Curve Thickness with Mesh Extrusions?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/260294/145249)