# 2D Curve functionality using geometry nodes - Blender 3.3 LTS

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

When using a curve as a path and adding another curve object as a bevel object, if I choose 2D for the path curve, the ends of the path match the bevel object - the resulting object looks uniform.  Changing the path curve to 3D causes the path to be distorted at the ends unless the path is cyclic.

[image]

Is there a way to get the same results using geometry nodes?
I have tried starting with a curve angle - which is created as 2D by default, but the results are the same - if the curve isn't cyclic, the ends are distorted.
I would like to do this in geometry nodes to take advantage of options such as asign material, reversing the curve via switch node and being able to quickly change profile curves.

This is the setup I have been toying with.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question may sound simple, but a solution with *Geometry Nodes* is unfortunately not trivial. Here is a possible answer: [Solving Uneven Profile Curve Thickness with Mesh Extrusions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/260294/145249)

Comment: Perfect!!!  That works.  And, it is so far over my head that I won't dare ask how.

Comment: You are welcome!