# Question regarding the Geometry node "Curve to Mesh"

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes, geometry

I'm trying to make a sweep with the geometry node but I can't achieve the result I want. My final object is totally deform.My goal is to obtain the left object.

For the left object I use the 2D curve option. Is it possible to activate this using some geometry node ?

Thanks you in advance for your response and your time.

[image]

Comment: @quellenform's answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/260294/35559) might fix it for you. No offence, but this question might be clobbered as a duplicate. If no fix. rephrase.

Comment: @RobinBetts is unfortunately correct here, and I wish the `Curve to Mesh` node had a switch like "constant thickness", but unfortunately it does not and the answer to this question has already been given. So please forgive me if I vote to close this question as a duplicate. If I am wrong, or your question is not answered by this, please be so kind and edit your question so that it can be reopened and clarified.

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Hi there, I am involved in addressing this issue in Blender. This is still in development but closing in on a solution and that'd be great if you could provide some feedback here: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/curve-to-mesh-node-even-thickness-feedback-thread/27271 - Thanks in advance!