# Translation of curve line is deforming and switch over ways in geometry node

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes, transforms

Im trying to create a road with polygones then use geometry nodes for control, lines, border, and more.
So my idea is to select the externe points of the mesh todrive a second line follow exactly the shape of external point.

My problems
1 - When I push my line I got some lines go in opposite ways.
2 - When I push the line extremely far from a border of the mesh the thickness is
deforming.

Do you have any ideas to force line to match with the mesh ?

Thanks you

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/260113/uneven-profile-curve-thickness-with-geometry-nodes-curve-to-mesh There's also a native solution in the works: https://developer.blender.org/D16829

Comment: @Kuboå Yes exactly what Im looking for thank you.