# Geometry Nodes: Mimic miter joints: Set Curve Point Radius based on vertex angle?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I wanted to use curve to mesh to add thickness to lines, but in this case I would want miter joints, or adjust corners at sharp angles to keep line thickness uniform. This might be achieved by setting the radius of curve points, and I imagine geometry nodes could automatically find the angle between a point and its partners and set the radius based on that.

I'm using a workaround using endpoint selection to automatically adjust for objects that are all square angles.

Comment: Do answers such as [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/260294/35559) help? It would also help to know if your miters are in 2D or 3D

Comment: Thank you, this would count as an answer, works perfectly.

Comment: Hi, @madscribbles.. glad that's a fix! Since no answer is required here, I think it's fair to close this out as a duplicate. If there's any problem with that.. edit for a re-open. Thanks.