# How to randomize the size of the same curve but with separate points and fix the weird deformity when using poly?

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

This is just a single curve, but it has separate points how do I randomize the size of each line?

The second point is that when using the spline type *Poly*, you get an irregular curvature depending on the angle.

Comment: Sorry, could you try to explain it differently? I didn’t understand your question.

Comment: It has the weird deformation of the curve when it's at a certain angle - Set Spline Type-> Poly

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66353/how-to-make-beveled-90-degree-corners-on-a-curve-better/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56079/how-can-i-make-a-perfect-sweep-with-bevel-object-in-bezier-curve3d-pipe