# is there an easier way of doing corners like this?

Tags: 3d-view

im doing models of interiors and one of the parts used molding around doors. is there a easy way of doing my corners other than having to get 2 frames and work inwards towards eachother?

[image]

Comment: Can you articulate your question a little better please? What do you mean two frames? Also please describe what you mean by working inward toward each other?

Comment: I know what he means. He's using two objects and trying to join them into a door frame. There are many methods to do this, One way is to use a cube scaled to the outer parameters of your frame, and then to subdivide it or loop-cut it to mark out the inner opening, then just delete the faces and bridge the open faces along the inside.

Comment: @maiira in the future crop your images and plese include in the image only information relevant to the question. To make a screen capture within blender, you can press Crl F3 and then choose to save the whole interface as an image or just the active window.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19709/extrude-along-path-sharp-corners/19717#19717

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty solid workflow if you don't desire to use multiple objects in the creation.

*I'm posting the image sequence for now, so I don't mess that part up, then coming back to give the commentary per image.*

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> >> Mesh >> Plane.

[image]

2. <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter edit mode.

[image]

3. <kbd>I</kbd> to inset the active face the desired amount.

[image]

4. <kbd>Delete</kbd> >> Only Faces.

[image]

5. Result of Deleting the face (giving you the major frame profile).

[image]

6. <kbd>A</kbd> to select all faces.

[image]

7. <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude the desired overall frame thickness.

[image]

8. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> >> <kbd>2</kbd> >> <kbd>LeftMouseButton</kbd> >> <kbd>RightMouseButton</kbd>

[image]

9. Click on the Face Mode icon/button.

[image]

10. <kbd>Z</kbd> >> Select the inner ring of faces (as shown).

[image]

11. With your cursor just outside the outer edge of the frame <kbd>E</kbd> >> <kbd>S</kbd> >> Move your mouse toward the center of the frame the desired amount >> <kbd>LeftMouseButton</kbd>

[image]

12. Click on the Edge Mode icon/button.

[image]

13. Select the Edge Loops at both the Inner Top & Inner Bottom of the frame.

[image]

14. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> >> Move your mouse outward the desired amount >> Either type the number of segments & hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> **OR** scroll up on the scroll wheel of your mouse the desired amount & <kbd>LeftMouseButton</kbd>.

[image]

15. Hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> & you are complete if you desire a 4-Sided frame.

[image]

16. If your desire is to have a 3-Sided frame >> <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter edit mode. >> <kbd>C</kbd> >> Select the bottom most horizontal edges of the frame.

[image]

17. <kbd>Delete</kbd> >> Only Edges & Faces.

[image]

18. The result is two empty holes that we must repair/fill.

[image]

19. Loop Select the left most hole. >> <kbd>F</kbd> to fill.

[image]

20. Loop Select the right most hole. >> <kbd>F</kbd> to fill.

[image]

21. Select both Edge Loops again.

[image]

22. <kbd>S</kbd> >> <kbd>Y</kbd> >> <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: From Steps 18-21 the profile looks wrong because I accidentally did some steps twice on my end trying to put the document together. I fixed this and the steps are good.